# Don't stop perl on: Quantifier in {,} bigger than 32766 in regex

Tags: perl

The question [Retain newlines for POD in case of PPR::uncomment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61307663/retain-newlines-for-pod-in-case-of-ppruncomment) was solved in the answer by defining a new method `decomment2` that leaves the newlines properly. All works quite well, but now I have a file to process with a very big HERE document (far to big to publish here so unfortunately a link to an external site): https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bn/asm/ppc.pl

When this file is processed through the `PPR::decomment2` I get the message:

```
Quantifier in {,} bigger than 32766 in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?s:.{ <-- HERE 39303})/ at /home/User/perl5/lib/perl5/Doxygen/Filter/Perl.pm line 1222.
```

Line 1222 is: `$str =~ m{ \A (?&PerlDocument) \Z` in the `PPR::decomment2` method.
At that moment, the Perl process terminates.

- Is there a way to increase this "32766" limit, i.e 2**15-2, in some way?
- Is there a way not to terminate the Perl process but set the `PPR::ERROR` or another flag, so this can be processed in the code?

Comment: I think you might want to raise this as an issue on the PPR repository on github. I'm pretty sure Damian will have an idea. Or he might pop by here.

Comment: The number 32766 comes from `REG_INFTY` in [`regcom.h`](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/regcomp.h#L252) : *"The default size for REG_INFTY is U16_MAX, which is the same as  USHORT_MAX (see perl.h)."*. See also [this](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2018/07/msg251413.html) thread for more information

Comment: @simbabque I tried to find the github repository for PPR, do you have a link to it?

Comment: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=PPR for reporting issues with it.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks just found that page as well, will go that way (did it in the mean time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and passed by the `eval` possibility.

Is there anything against a construct like:

```
eval {
   my $mystr = PPR::decomment2($str)
   # do some local dependent stuff
};
if ($@) {
  # do the local handling if the error
}
```

Is there anything against a construct like this?

Edit (April 23, 2013): a patch has been made by the maintainer of the PPR package (Damian Conway). The package number is 25.

Comment: This is the "native" way to handle exceptions in Perl and there is absolutely nothing wrong with using it; it's a good thing. (An exception in Perl being the `die`, and there are modules that wrap the `eval` mechanism.)  But it won't magically fix that 32k-limit-broken regex, it'll only keep the program running.

Comment: @zdim thanks. I want that the program remains running as it can still give valuable information (as I will use another algorithm in case the decommenting fails).

Comment: Yes, precisely the point of (this form of) `eval`, to catch what would otherwise terminate the program, and exit cleanly and orderly -- or recover (continue), as you intend to do.

Answer (score 2):

As a point of information, the max value was doubled in Perl 5.30 to 65534.